# Create pointer to unsigned char[] and pass it to sf::SoundBuffer::loadFromMemory

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, sfml, memcpy

In my game I have a map `std::map<Sound, sf::SoundBuffer> mySounds` that I use as a resource holder for sounds.

`Sound` is an enum that looks like this:

```
enum class Sound {
  SOUND_ONE,
  SOUND_TWO,
  SOUND_THREE,
  NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS
};
```

Now, in order to load the sounds I currently use `sf::SoundBuffer::loadFromFile`, and the code looks like this:

```
std::vector<std::string> paths;
paths.resize(static_cast<unsigned int>(Sound::NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS));
paths[static_cast<std::size_t>(Sound::SOUND_ONE)] = "sound1.ogg";
paths[static_cast<std::size_t>(Sound::SOUND_TWO)] = "sound2.ogg";
paths[static_cast<std::size_t>(Sound::SOUND_THREE)] = "sound3.ogg";

for (std::size_t i = 0; i < static_cast<std::size_t>(Sound::NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS); ++i) {
  mySounds[static_cast<Sound>(i)].loadFromFile("./data/" + paths[i]);
}
```

This works fine.

**Now to the problem:**

For my release build I want to convert all sounds to byte arrays (using a tool called bin2h) and then use `sf::SoundBuffer::loadFromMemory()`.

The arrays would look like this:

```
unsigned char RES_SOUND_ONE[] = {0x4f,0x67,0x67,0x53,...};
unsigned char RES_SOUND_TWO[] = {0x52,0x88,0x29,0x47,...};
unsigned char RES_SOUND_THREE[] = {0x96,0x65,0x59,0x02,...};
```

If I only had a single sound, I could simply write:

```
mySound.loadFromMemory(RES_SOUND_ONE, sizeof(RES_SOUND_ONE));
```

and it would work perfectly.

I have more than one sound though, so I was thinking of having a pointer inside the for-loop (initially just a null pointer).

Then I'd set the pointer to the appropriate byte array based on which loop index I'm currently at (see `switch` in the code below).

Then I'd pass that pointer to the data to the `loadFromMemory` function.

```
for (std::size_t i = 0; i < static_cast<std::size_t>(Sound::NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS); ++i) {
  void *buffer = nullptr;
  switch (static_cast<Sound>(i)) {
    case Sound::SOUND_ONE:   { buffer = (unsigned char*)RES_SOUND_ONE; } break;
    case Sound::SOUND_TWO:   { buffer = (unsigned char*)RES_SOUND_TWO; } break;
    case Sound::SOUND_THREE: { buffer = (unsigned char*)RES_SOUND_THREE; } break;
  }
  mySounds[static_cast<Sound>(i)].loadFromMemory(buffer, sizeof(buffer));
}
```

The SFML error message is:

`Failed to open sound file from memory (format not supported)`

I'm doing something very wrong

I also tried various other things like `memcpy` and it all results in failure lol

So basically what I'm asking is: How do I create a pointer to an unsigned char array and pass it to the SFML function `sf::SoundBuffer::loadFromMemory(const void *data, size_t sizeInBytes)`

Comment: you sure that you arnt passing a null pointer to this function ? you have one handled value (NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely with your call to `loadFromMemory()`.

In particular, the value for `sizeof(buffer)` is likely to be a constant based on how much memory a pointer takes. (For example 8 bytes on a 64-bit platform.)

I doubt that will be large enough to contain the sound info... :)

You want to pass the size of the array. To follow your pattern:

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < static_cast<size_t>(Sound::NUMBER_OF_SOUNDS); ++i)
{
    unsigned char *buf = nullptr;
    size_t siz = 0;
    switch (static_cast<Sound>(i))
    {
        case Sound::SOUND_ONE:
            buf = RES_SOUND_ONE;
            siz = sizeof (RES_SOUND_ONE);
            break;
        case Sound::SOUND_TWO:
            buf = RES_SOUND_TWO;
            siz = sizeof (RES_SOUND_TWO);
            break;
        case Sound::SOUND_THREE:
            buf = RES_SOUND_THREE;
            siz = sizeof (RES_SOUND_THREE);
            break;
    }
    mySounds[static_cast<Sound>(i)].loadFromMemory(buf, siz);
}
```